# How to access ui from main window in another qdialog?

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow

I am having trouble accessing a QTextEdit from a main window in another form. Please help.

```
void properties::on_okWordPushButton_clicked()
{
    if (ui->wordcombo->currentText() == "All Words") {

        int wordCount = notepad->textEdit->toPlainText().split(QRegExp("(\\s|\\n|\\r)+"), QString::SkipEmptyParts).count();
        ui->wordcountlabel->setText(QString::number(wordCount));

    }
}
```

I am getting an error since I cannot read notepad->textEdit

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Sematic issue. 31:25 'notepad' does not refer to a value. I have included "notepad.h" and "ui_notepad.h" and notepad instance is set to public. I can share my entire file if that helps.

Comment: dont pas the whole ui, instead connect the window and the dialog and use signals slots to pass the minimal required data

Comment: It can be done by using `signal/slot` between the two windows/forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this, the `ui` is a private member of a widget, create a function that returns or sets what you need!

Answer (score 1):

You can use at least 2 possibilities:

1. Dirty way:
   On form creation, pass pointer to your QTextEdit:

```cpp
// mainwindow.cpp
auto myProperties = new properties(notepad->textEdit);
...

// properties.h
QTextEdit *outerEditor;

// properties.cpp
properties::properties(QTextEdit *editor) {
 outerEditor = editor;
 ...
}
```

Then, on your slot you can use:

```
int wordCount = editor->toPlainText().split(QRegExp("(\\s|\\n|\\r)+"), QString::SkipEmptyParts).count();
```

2. Qt-way:
   Remember - signals/slots are awesome.

Just after form creation, you can connect signal from MainWindow to properties passing text in your QTextEdit and store it locally:

```cpp
// MainWindow.cpp
auto myProperties = new properties(notepad->textEdit);
connect(this->textEdit, QOverload<QString>::of(&QTextEdit::valueChanged), myProperties, GetNewValue);

// properties.h
void GetNewValue(QString val);

// properties.cpp
void properties::GetNewValue(QString val) {
    ui->wordcountlabel->setText(QString::number(val.toPlainText().split(QRegExp("(\\s|\\n|\\r)+"), QString::SkipEmptyParts).count());
}
```